# Cannot apply knockout bindings, even with the default tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to apply bindings to a specific DOM element, but I am having no success with either my code or the example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html)

this is what I have right now:

```
var Test = function(first, last){
    this.first = ko.observable(first);
    this.last = ko.observable(last);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Test("Hello", "World"), $("#Element").get());
```

I keep getting this

```
Uncaught Error: ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node
```

I have tried giving it only the jQuery element to no avail as well.  I can confirm that $("#Element") is part of the DOM both visually and through console testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any arguments `$("#Element").get()` does the following ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/get/)):

> Retrieve the DOM **elements** matched by the jQuery object.

so it returns an **array** of the matched elements even if this array contains only one element.

So you need to use the overload which takes an index:

```
ko.applyBindings(new Test("Hello", "World"), $("#Element").get(0));
```

Or index the returned array:

```
ko.applyBindings(new Test("Hello", "World"), $("#Element").get()[0]);
```

Comment: or remove the get() entirely...$("#Element")[0]...or bypass jQuery and go document.getElementById('Element') ... boo-ya

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's .get() function, with no parameters, returns the collection. If you want just the DOM node reference, you need to pass index 0 to it, like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new Test("Hello", "World"), $("#Element").get(0));
```

Comment: `$('#Element")` you're using a mix of `'` and `"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 var Test = function(first, last){
   this.first = ko.observable(first);
   this.last = ko.observable(last);
 }

 ko.applyBindings(new Test("Hello", "World"), $("#Element").get(0));
```

make sure that DOM element that has an ID of "Element" is existing